# Creating an Array in Spark Scala (seeded)

Tags: arrays, scala, random, seed

How do you create random seeded arrays in Scala? I would want to have a random array but this random array must be the same all through out the function.

Using `scala.util`, we can do, for example

```
val arr1 = Array.fill[Float](Random.nextFloat)
```

However, `arr1` changes every time the process goes through it.

Since we also have seeds in Scala, I've tried doing:

```
val rndm = Random(4)
val arr1 = Array.fill[Float](rndm.nextFloat)
```

Still, it changes every time even if there is a seed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a random generator with a seed,

```
val r = new scala.util.Random(100)
```

To re-create the same sequence of pseudo-random values you need to "reset" the generator, otherwise it will add new (possibly) different values to the next sequences,

```
scala> val r = new scala.util.Random(100)
r: scala.util.Random = scala.util.Random@5b1dd206

scala> Array.fill(2)(r.nextFloat)
res6: Array[Float] = Array(0.7220096, 0.7346627)

scala> val r = new scala.util.Random(100)
r: scala.util.Random = scala.util.Random@6f371390

scala> Array.fill(2)(r.nextFloat)
res7: Array[Float] = Array(0.7220096, 0.7346627)
```